# How to receive this result in SQL

Tags: sql

I have two tables – customer and product and I have 10 customers and 5 products.

I can join this for example by query:

```
select 
    ca.id as customer_id,p.id as product_id
from 
    customeraccount ca  
left join 
    product p on ca.id = p.customeraccountid
```

How to recive new table which is similar to Cartesian but which isn’t Cartesian, like this:

[image]

Flaq is a variable which says if this customer have this product.

Comment: Please always tag the actual DBMS (vendor and version)...

Comment: Add some sample table data, as formatted text, and also the expected result also as formatted text.

Comment: Also add Table structure.

Comment: http://meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/285551/why-may-i-not-upload-images-of-code-on-so-when-asking-a-question/285557#285557

Comment: Ok ! Thanks and sorry ;)

Comment: Hi ann, As you are rather new here, please allow me one hint: It is very kind of you to say *Thanks*, but it would be even kinder, to tick the acceptance check below the (best) answer's vote counter. This will 1) mark this issue as solved 2) make it easier for followers to find the best solution 3) pay points to the answerer and 4) pay points to you. Once you've crossed the 15 points border yourself, you are asked to vote on contributions. This is the SO-way to say thank you. Happy Coding!

Answer (score 1):

CROSS JOIN may solve your problem

```
SELECT ca.id as customer_id,
       p.id as product_id,
       CASE WHEN ca.id=p.customeraccountid THEN 1 ELSE 0 END AS Flag
FROM  customeraccount ca  
CROSS JOIN product p
```

Answer (score 1):

If you have *two tables* you shoul re-think your design. You should at least have a table for your customers, one for your products and one for actual sales (or whatever you want to do here...).

As you are rather new here, please allow me one hint: Help the SO community with a good [MCVE](https://stackoverflow.com/help/mcve). Here I create one for you:

SQL-Server syntax...

```
DECLARE @customer TABLE(CustomerID INT);
INSERT INTO @customer VALUES(1001),(1002),(1003);
DECLARE @prod TABLE(ProdID INT);
INSERT INTO @prod VALUES(1),(2),(3);
DECLARE @sales TABLE(CustomerID INT,ProdID INT);
INSERT INTO @sales VALUES(1001,1),(1001,3)
                        ,(1002,1),(1002,2)
                        ,(1003,2);

SELECT c.CustomerID
      ,p.ProdID
      ,CASE WHEN s.CustomerID IS NULL THEN 0 ELSE 1 END AS HasSale 
FROM @customer AS c
CROSS JOIN @prod AS p
LEFT JOIN @sales AS s ON s.ProdID=p.ProdID AND s.CustomerID=c.CustomerID
```

The result

```
Cust   Prod HasSales
1001    1   1
1001    2   0
1001    3   1
1002    1   1
1002    2   1
1002    3   0
1003    1   0
1003    2   1
1003    3   0
```